# STS 3.8.3 Mac-OS forgets all settings (and installed plugins) on reboot

Tags: eclipse, macos, spring-tool-suite

So very weird, first time I ever saw this, problem install STS version 3.8.3-release on Macbook Pro running mac osSerria v10.12.3.  Here's what's I do:

1. Down load the STS distro **spring-tool-suite-3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz** from https://spring.io/tools/sts/all
2. Move the zip file to my **Applications** folder
3. Extract the distro.  This creates the *sts-bundle* folder, and; under that, the STS programs exists.
4. I then just run STS.  Since this is a first-time I **do** get the pop-up for selecting the default workspace.  I change it to where I want the workspace and I also check the "Don't ask again".
5. Install some plug-ins, do work, everything is normal.
6. I **can** exit the app throughout the day and, when I go back in all is cool.

Now...the problem...
 1. Shutdown the laptop for the day.  This is to say I select Apple->Shut Down..
 2. The next day I come in, boot-up the laptop.
 3. Open Applications and select STS and run STS.

At this point, I get the "Select default workspace" popup again...all my preferences, and installed plug-ins are **forgotten**, and it's like I'm running the application again for the first time??  It is especially weird that any plug-ins I installed are also forgotten??

I have completely removed STS, and reinstalled several times and it is pretty consistent.  Also, I have installed STS on several iMac desktops without issue.  This smells like a *permissions* problem but not errors just...all customized preferences are simply gone.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried not putting it under `/Applications`?

Comment: Good point.  No I haven't.  I'll give that a shot next.  Perhaps under `shared` or something.  I'll hack a bit more and post the results.

Comment: Follow-up.  Installing STS anyplace, including `Users/Shared` doesn't seem to make any difference.  I can enter/exit the app all day without trouble; but if I reboot the laptop, all my plug-ins are gone.  My workspace projects are still there, but all my customized preferences, including any plug-ins I installed, are simply gone; and I have to reinstall them.

Comment: What is /Users/Shared? Is that your own home directory?

Comment: It is just another folder off of the hard drive's root folder.  Also, I `assumed`, based on the names of the folders, that any user could r/w into this folder.  Here is where I tried installing:
/Applications
/Users/myUserId/Applications
/Users/Shared

I just can't figure-out why, on a machine reboot, everything reverts back to the factory settings.  I have 3 plug-ins I like to use regarding `Gradle` and it is a pain-in-the-A to have to reinstall on a regular basis.  Also, on an `iMac` this doesn't happen.  But, this is my first experience with a `Macbook Pro`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is App Translocation, which is done by OSX. For details, take a look here, we analyzed this in detail:

[STS.app on Mac 10.12.1 always creates a new org.springsource.sts folder in .eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724146/sts-app-on-mac-10-12-1-always-creates-a-new-org-springsource-sts-folder-in-ecli)

Comment: Good morning.  Hey `Martin`, that was it!!  Several days ago, I moved the entire `sts-bundle` folder over to /Applications, and then ran the STS.app.  I did notice that, in the hidden .eclipse folder there were several folders as you mentioned.  Needless to say, after just coping over, using `Finder` the STS.app to /Applications everything worked like a top.  I appreciate the assist.