# Eclipse (STS) reverts to being a fresh instal every time I open it on my Mac

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I have started using mac recently. I downloaded STS and started coding in it. I installed few plugins I needed to work. After a days work I shut down and started it the next day and all off a sudden it again asked for workspace location even if I checked the default location do not ask again checkbox the last time and again I selected the workspace location and checked the checkbox again and now the plugins I installed the previous day are not there I had to install them all over again and it's the same everyday. Can anyone help we with this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724146/sts-app-on-mac-10-12-1-always-creates-a-new-org-springsource-sts-folder-in-ecli

Comment: @MartinLippert I happen do what the thread said and I the eclipse on my mac still ends up acting as a fresh one after I start my mac the next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue on Mac Os Sierra. I'm not a Mac user myself and not too familiar with the details, but it has something to do with a security feature of Mac OS which is trying to 'sandbox' apps by randomizing thier startup location. This makes STS / Eclipse think its a fresh install and unable to locate any settings / state saved from before.

You can find more info in the [STS New and Noteworthy](http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v384/NewAndNoteworthy.html) under "Known Issues".

Perhaps these are the most important snippets of information:

> If you unpackage the STS archive on macOS Sierra and use it without moving it to a different location on your drive, macOS Sierra Gatekeeper activates a security feature called "Path Randomization" for the app
>
> ...
>
> As a workaround, please move the STS.app bundle to a different location on your drive before starting it.

Comment: I happen do what the thread said and I the eclipse on my mac still ends up acting as a fresh one after I start my mac the next day.

Comment: I had to move it the applications folder. I extracted the zip file to Downloads folder and then moved the folder to Documents and I still had the same problem. But when I moved the STS app file to Applications folder it seems to work fine now. Thanks for the help.